# Seaborn Striplot data visualization not applying colors to markers/bars/strips

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, visualization

When creating a stripplot with seaborn, the code creates a striplot perfectly. Applies colors to the legend and all. Except the color is not applying to the various strips in within the stripplot. Appreciate the seaborn/matplotlib experts here, because I am at a loss. Code is below. Picture attached below with my results.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

#set seaborn plotting aesthetics
sns.set_style("whitegrid")

data = [[2016.0, 0.4862, 0.4115, 0.3905, 0.3483, 0.1196],
 [2017.0, 0.4471, 0.4096, 0.3725, 0.2866, 0.1387],
 [2018.0, 0.4748, 0.4016, 0.3381, 0.2905, 0.2012],
 [2019.0, 0.4705, 0.4247, 0.3857, 0.3333, 0.2457],
 [2020.0, 0.4755, 0.4196, 0.3971, 0.3825, 0.2965]]

# cols = ['attribute_time', '100-81%', '80-61%', '60-41%', '40-21%', '20-0%']
cols = ['attribute_time', '100-81 percentile', '80-61 percentile', '60-41 percentile', '40-21 percentile', '20-0 percentile']

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)

# Just to get rid of the decimals.
df['attribute_time'] = df['attribute_time'].astype('int') 
print(df)
df.columns = ['attribute_time', '100-81 percentile', '80-61 percentile', '60-41 percentile', '40-21 percentile', '20-0 percentile']
df = df.melt(id_vars = ['attribute_time'],
    value_name = 'pct_value',
    var_name = 'pct_range')
print(df.head(20))

print(df['pct_range'].unique())

# # Create a dictionary mapping subgroup values to colors
palette_colors = dict(zip(list(df['pct_range'].unique()), ['blue', 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple']))
print(palette_colors)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for year, value in zip(df['attribute_time'],df['pct_value']):
    ax.text(year - 2016, value, str(value), ha = 'center', va = 'bottom', fontsize = 'small',)

sns.stripplot(
    data = df,
    x = 'attribute_time',
    y = 'pct_value',
    hue = 'pct_range',
    palette=palette_colors,
    jitter = False,
    marker = '_',
    size = 25,
    linewidth = 2,
    ax = ax
).legend(fontsize=7)

plt.show()
```

[image: stripplot without colors appliers to markers]

Comment: My view is that given that changing the marker type produces the intended result, it seems that markers that can be set by facecolor can and others cannot. So I thought it would need to be rewritten to be completed in matplotlib.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matplotlib has two types of markers. Most are filled (e.g. as circle with a border).  Some are unfilled (e.g. a horizontal line).

Seaborn uses the hue color only for the interior, and uses a fixed color (default black) for the borders (edges).  If I try to run your code, I get a warning from matplotlib complaining that a face color is given for unfilled markers.  You can simply put `edgecolor='face'` to give the face color to the edges. (Matplotlib still gives the same warning, but does color the markers via the hue color.)

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

# set seaborn plotting aesthetics
sns.set_style("whitegrid")

data = [[2016.0, 0.4862, 0.4115, 0.3905, 0.3483, 0.1196],
        [2017.0, 0.4471, 0.4096, 0.3725, 0.2866, 0.1387],
        [2018.0, 0.4748, 0.4016, 0.3381, 0.2905, 0.2012],
        [2019.0, 0.4705, 0.4247, 0.3857, 0.3333, 0.2457],
        [2020.0, 0.4755, 0.4196, 0.3971, 0.3825, 0.2965]]
cols = ['attribute_time', '100-81 percentile', '80-61 percentile', '60-41 percentile', '40-21 percentile', '20-0 percentile']

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)
# Just to get rid of the decimals.
df['attribute_time'] = df['attribute_time'].astype('int')
df_long = df.melt(id_vars=['attribute_time'],
             value_name='pct_value',
             var_name='pct_range')
# Create a dictionary mapping subgroup values to colors
palette_colors = dict(zip(list(df_long['pct_range'].unique()), plt.cm.get_cmap('Set1').colors))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for year, value in zip(df_long['attribute_time'], df_long['pct_value']):
     ax.text(year - 2016, value, str(value), ha='center', va='bottom', fontsize='small', )

sns.stripplot(data=df_long,
              x='attribute_time',
              y='pct_value',
              hue='pct_range',
              palette=palette_colors,
              jitter=False,
              marker='_',
              size=25,
              linewidth=2,
              edgecolor='face',
              ax=ax)
ax.legend(fontsize=7)

plt.show()
```

[image: sns.stripplot with edgecolor='face']